# Find the slope of three columns in an oracle table

Tags: oracle, toad, trend

[image]

Hi , I am using Toad to access Oracle DB . I have a table such as above which i need to find whether the column 1 , 2 and 3 have a positive trend or negative trend with a value . Is there a way to do this in oracle sql .THanks alot

Comment: What do you expect to report for the fourth row?  Its overall trend, over three data points, is flat, though it does drop and then regain.

Comment: hi, i need some positive or negative value indicating whether it is positive or negative trend.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the below is fine

```
select decode(sign(col3-col2),1,decode(sign(col2-col1),1,1,-1),-1) as slope
FROM your table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using:

```
Select 
(Col3 - col2) + (col2 - col1)
From your_table
```

This query, if returns negative number then slope us negative trend and if positiove then slope is positive trend. But 0 represents that there is no slope at all.

Also, its value represents the intensity of the slope.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

We can subtract the col3 from col2 and then add with col2 minus col1. This will give an effective rise or low and then we can identify the slope.

```
select temp.*,(col2-col1)+(col3-col2) slope from temp;
```